# Responsive image with CSS animated dangling key that should stay responsively in place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Good day,

I am trying to make a nice animation for a website.
It should be relatively simple. So I have drawn a hand and a BMW car key. Used a `css` code to make it swing and yes it works.

[image: BMW car keys offered by hand]

However it is responsive but not in the way I want it to be. I'd like the key to stay in place where it is. However it is moving just about anywhere depending on the screen size.

I could of course use screen size in `css`. But I don't want to use screen size. I want to be able to place the animation about anywhere where I'd like it to be.

However when resizing the key moves also anywhere where it would like to be :-/

Probably my approach is entirely wrong. But at this point this is what I'd could come up with. Maybe it is right. But I hope that someone could tell me where and how to correct my mistakes.

My HTML code (of course bootstrap and others are linked in the header)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes swinging {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swinging {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
}

.swingimage {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
  animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

.key_hand {
  /*
        background-image: url('arm_hand.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%; */
  min-height: 900px;
}

.key_hand>.complete_arm {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.key_hand>.bmw_key {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -390pt;
  left: 7%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
  animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 key_hand">
      <img src="arm_hand.png" class="complete_arm" />
      <img src="complete_bmw_key.png" class="bmw_key" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created the following pen. Hoping to shed some light on this case.
https://codepen.io/slalex/pen/GXxMmg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing `min-height: 900px` from `.key_hand`, and replacing `pt` by `%` for the `top` positioning of `.key_hand > .bmw_key`, it should be great. [Here is the result](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdRJVb)

Hope it look like what you were waiting for, and bravo for your drawing !

Comment: Super!! Thanks!! Yeah it took me some time but the result is satisfactory.